# LLVM - How AST can be transformed to IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-gcc, llvm-ir

I know that an `AST` generated by the parser is used to generate IR in the frontend.

I am wondering how AST to be parsed and then transformed to IR (prob assembly or bitcode),

AST is a tree, what are the steps involved in the transformation from AST to IR.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Emitting `LLVM IR from Clang ASTs` happens in Clang's `code gen` stage. The code for this stage lives in `lib/CodeGen/` (relative to Clang's source root). There's no need to parse the AST since Clang has the AST in an in-memory data structure. Code generation is essentially a recursive walk of the AST that emits IR into a `Module`. If there's any specific step of it that interests you, the best way to examine it would be to look in the code.

Comment: Thanks Eli. Would you mind to explain a bit more about what happened during the "walking of the AST that emits IR into a Module" ?

Comment: I mean, how AST can be transformed to IR ? Is that a mapping file or something else ?

Comment: @Sam explaining the process in detail will take a lot of time and space here, you'd better off checking the source by yourself

Comment: @MarcoA., thanks for your reply. Would it be possible to give a very brief explanation so that I can have a general sense before digging into the code ?

Comment: @Sam: the link given by mishr is an excellent simple example of emitting LLVM IR from a simple AST. Simple because the input language is simple. The real Clang AST represent languages that are anything but simple (C++), so walking them is very complex as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will go through the link.

Comment: Here's an update to @shrm 's link: http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html. As a starting point, the tutorial first provides a simple AST implementation. It then explains how a unique `codegen()` function can be written for each type of AST node you have. Then, simply walk the AST (calling the `codegen()` functions along the way) to generate the LLVM.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is to find where the `codeGen` process starts in clang. Can someone please give me some pointers? Thanks