# How to generate assembly code from the Abstract syntax tree?

Tags: compiler-construction

I wanted to know how to generate assembly code from the abstract syntax tree?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a master in compiler construction. But if you are a beginner, I guess this answer will help.

First of all, assembly is a platform dependant. You have to decide for which platform you are going to generate assembly code. You can refer to the `instruction set architecture` for this.

After finalizing that, there are two ways you can generate assembly code.

1. Generate assembly manually
2. Using a library

If you are going to generate assembly manually, you should have a good knowledge of instruction set architecture. You have to traverse through the AST and convert nodes into assembly code. You can use a design pattern like `Visitor` or `Listener` aka `Observer pattern` to traverse through the AST.

Also, you can use a library like [Asmjit](https://asmjit.com/) for machine code generation as well.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) will help you to get some knowledge about assembly code.

Here are few other Stackoverflow answers that may help you.

- [Compiling an AST to Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445522/compiling-an-ast-to-assembly)
- [LLVM - How AST can be transformed to IR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652016/llvm-how-ast-can-be-transformed-to-ir)
- [How Does Assembly Code Generation Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030481/how-does-assembly-code-generation-work)